# Dynamic JList implementation

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a list of entities where each entity render into widget based on `JPanel`. Widgets have dynamic behaviour - once placed on panel it can be changed by underlying entity. This happens automaticaly. Moreover some widgets can be resized by different actions, on button click for example.

The question is how to organise them into something like `JList` but without rubber stamp technics. In other words I wanna `JList` where each item rendered with cellrenderer stay "alive".

Right now I have implemented quick-and-dirty component based on `JPanel` with vertical `BoxLayout`, it uses `JList's` renderer component and it's model... but my implementation is too dirty...

Um.. yeah, using `JTable` is not suitable too.

Do you have some ideas?

Comment: for better help sooner please post http://sscce.org/ here

Comment: You really need a better understanding of Swing MVC; everything you need is already made available to you..you just need to know how to wire it all together to account for your entity.

Comment: yeah. My Swing knowledge is not perfect and I see that it is available to construct component from pieces, but I hope some stable and tested implementation exists. I don't want to reinvent bicycle this night.

Comment: sscce is rather hard right now. current implementation have a lot of dummy code and method signatures itself won't be too informative. So lets consider I talk about JList with component placing, not rubber stamping.

Comment: _I talk about JList with component placing, not rubber stamping_ In Swing, that's a contradiction in itself ;-)

Comment: I suppose rubber stamping in some swing components is not a feature. This is because performance reasons. I hope collection of smth about 20 panels wont slow down system.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want rubber stamping to take place then you'll have to create your own JList implementation that uses actual components.

You could try and work around the rubber stamping effect by caching each component for each row in your renderer and bind values into it and return that instance when JList asks the renderer for it.  This is pretty risky because if you  have 20 rows being displayed you'll have to cache 20 instances in your renderer, and only when the row isn't visible can you reuse one.  That would mean if you had 5 unique configurations (A,B,C,D,E) of components you might have 10 of type A, 5 of type B, 2 of type C, and 3 of type D, and 0 of type E being displayed.  However, you can't simply reuse one of those components without knowing if its being displayed or not.  So you'd have to take into account if the row is being displayed and if it's the right type for the row you are rendering.  And you'll have to clean up after the row is hidden.

Another option is make a single component for the row that encapsulates all X variations you have and put those on a CardLayout.  Then you can simply cache one per row being displayed, and simply swap the card being displayed upon rendering that row.  I think that might be the simplest option for you.

The harder part is going to be routing events click mouse clicks, keyboard events, etc to those active components to have them respond like normal components.  Re-rendering the buttons when the user clicks them, and so forth is going to be challenging.  Not impossible, but tedious.

Finally, variable row height JList is a pain.  Especially in your calculations to figure out if a row is displayed or not because you can't simply do easy math like:  int rowHeight = jlist.getHeight / model.size().  It doesn't work.  You have to calculate each row's height and them up to figure out if a row is visible or not.

Doing what you're talking about is a lot of work, and very tricky coding to work around some of the assumptions of JList to make it work.  In the end you might find it easier just to implement your own List control that makes different design decisions.  Either way its going to require you are good at Swing to get it to work.

Comment: Yeah. Quick scolling of JList sources make me sure that it is too hard for me right now to base on existing component. My Swing knowledge not so deep. As I write earlier I implement some buggy workaround based on layout, scrollpanel and jpanel which sometimes work as I want. But i still hope earlier somebody already met such problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I don't find any implementation of such component. Let it be first one.
https://github.com/wertlex/JActiveList

P.S. I don't think this is proper way implementation... but it works.

Answer (score -1):

use JList and ActionListener XD

Comment: to do what and how exactly? -1